# add pagination navigation to swipejs carousel

Tags: jquery, pagination

Im trying to add a pagination navigation to a carousel using the swipe.js similar to

http://swipejs.com/

Desired effect will mean clicking 1-5 in the  will link to that slide on the carousel

**LIVE SAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/tJH3M/2/

```
    <div id='mySwipe' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><b>0</b></div>
    <div><b>1</b></div>
    <div><b>2</b></div>
    <div><b>3</b></div>
    <div><b>4</b></div>
    <div><b>5</b></div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Man, you started the bounty.. but didn't care to check out the answers or comment if it worked out.. in last 7 days..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin has a function `.slide` which allows you to navigate to desired slide.

The syntax is,

```
.slide(pos, duration)
```

So add an ID to your nav say `#nav`, then add a click handler to `li` and inside the handler, call `.slide` with the `index + 1` (`$(this).index() + 1`) as pos.

```
$('#nav li').on ('click', function () {
    window.mySwipe.slide($(this).index() + 1, 200);
});
```

<s>**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xYDf4/</s>

<s>Added some styles to highlight the selection http://jsfiddle.net/xYDf4/1/</s>

**Edit:** Added conditions to sync the pager and Next/Prev buttons to mark them selected **http://jsfiddle.net/xYDf4/2**

```
$('#mySwipePrev').on('click', function () {
   mySwipe.prev();

   $navLi.removeClass('selected');
   $navLi.eq(mySwipe.getPos() - 1).addClass('selected');
});
$('#mySwipeNext').on('click', function () {
   mySwipe.next();
   $navLi.removeClass('selected');
   $navLi.eq(mySwipe.getPos() - 1).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Numbers are not got highlighted when we click next / previous button!

Comment: @Venkat highlighting added when clicking next / prev button, even though that was not in OP.

Comment: Is there a quick way to make it auto scroll too?

Comment: @JamesBond Please post a fiddle where I can look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try this similar plugin which may achieve your task.

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email
http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/