# swipejs plugin - pagination bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination, slider

I'm trying to implement swipejs slider to my site.
All is well, except that I need to set up pagination dots.
I've followed this exchange to get started [add pagination navigation to swipejs carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285494/add-pagination-navigation-to-swipejs-carousel)

My issue is that when you click the last pagination dot twice, all of my slide images show up at the same time. I figure this has to do with the index() javascript logic that ahs been implemented, but I am stumped as how to prevent this from happening.

html:

```
<div id='swipeslider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div>
      <a><img></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a><img></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a><img></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a><img></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a><img></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a><img></a>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- swipe-wrap -->
  <nav id="swipenav_container">
    <ul id="swipenav">
      <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
      <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
      <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
      <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
      <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
      <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div> <!-- #swipeslider -->
```

jquery:

```
 window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipeslider'), {
      startSlide: 1,
      speed: 400,
      auto: 3000,
      continuous: true,
      disableScroll: false,
    });

    var $navLi = $('#swipenav li');
    $navLi.on ('click', function () {
      window.mySwipe.slide($(this).index() + 1, 200);
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

/* center slide images in slide-wrap div */
.swipe-wrap img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#swipenav {
  text-align: center;
}

#swipenav_container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#swipenav_container ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#swipenav li {
  display: inline;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #666;
  margin: 3px;
}

.dot:hover {
  background-color: #999;
}

.selected .dot {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: can we see this bug live somewhere?

Comment: hmm thats a tough one. It's on my VM running locally, and our beta server is password protected. Here's a screen grab: http://i681.photobucket.com/albums/vv171/eloist/bug_zpsa6ad22d5.jpg

Comment: can you replicate it on http://jsfiddle.net make sure the number of slides matches the number of your dots

Comment: I recreated in jsfiddle, but the behavior is not the same... ughhh http://jsfiddle.net/zf4YF/

Comment: you gotta add the swipe js as an external source

Comment: I did that, and the behavior is still not the same. I decided to implement a different slider with touch and pagination included out of the box.

Comment: ok sounds good, if this question is no longer valid, could you delete it when you get a chance? thank you